# using vlc as rtsp server

Tags: vlc, rtsp

I'm running the following command to create a rtsp server:

```
cvlc -vvv VM_parkrun_720p60_8000.h264 --rtsp-host 10.0.1.3:554 
--sout '#rtp{name=coucou,port=554,sdp=rtsp://10.0.1.3:8080/test.sdp}'
```

When I see the generated sdp, I'm surprised to see 0.0.0.0 next to the "c" entry:

```
[0xb4f00aa8] stream_out_rtp stream out debug: sdp=
v=0
o=- 15575407803244807341 15575407803244807341 IN IP4 nde-OptiPlex-980
s=coucou
i=N/A
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
t=0 0
a=tool:vlc 2.0.8
a=recvonly
a=type:broadcast
a=charset:UTF-8
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
b=RR:0
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1
```

Is this related to my route table ? Have I done something wrong with my options ?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it means your server's socket is [bound to](http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind) `0.0.0.0` which means all the interface addresses at your computer.